# Where should I put gradle.properties in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

Where should I put the gradle.properties file in Jenkins?

I'm using version 1.21 of the Gradle plugin, but it isn't finding the properties file when I put it in the user home .gradle directory.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATED**

The Gradle plugin looks by default in the workspace of each project for a gradle.properties file. In order to use one file across all jobs, you need to set your gradle home in your job configurations as follows, by adding the following under 'switches':

```
-Dgradle.user.home=$HOME/.gradle
```

Comment: may be at home folder jenkins?

Comment: Are you sure that you are putting `gradle.properties` into the correct Gradle user home? I don't think the Jenkins plugin is involved in finding it.

Answer (score 27):

The Gradle plugin looks by default in the workspace of each project for a gradle.properties file. In order to use one file across all jobs, you need to set your gradle home in your job configurations as follows, by adding the following under 'switches':

```
-Dgradle.user.home=$HOME/.gradle
```

Comment: +1 from me! However, I'm using different nodes with different user-homes, so I configured it like -Dgradle.user.home=${GRADLE_USER_HOME} and defined the environment variable with value 'C:\Users\<myUserName>\.gradle' in the configuration of each node. Hope it'll help someone with similar situation as me.

Answer (score 5):

In your Jenkins webpage, you can see 'user.home' property in 'System Information' page. (for slve, check slave's 'System Information' page)
You'd put gradle.properties under 'user.home'/.gradle/ folder and every gradle job could see that properties.
Adding switch is not work if your job runs on the other slave environment (ie. Windows system)

Comment: This save me for our Multi Configuration Project. That executes the same build for windows and linux

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of @devmojopum, make sure "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace" is not checked in your job configuration.

[image: Gradle Configuration]

Answer (score -7):

Just put gradle.properties next to your build.gradle.

Regards,
Olle

Comment: gradle.properties can have authentication details inside them. Not great to put that in a repository. Especially if that repository is public.