# Issue finding gradle.properties in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am working in a project with private information in ${*user.home*}/.gradle/gradle.properties but when I try to build the project from Jenkins Gradle cannot find the properties. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169638/where-should-i-put-gradle-properties-in-jenkins) solution but I face the same issue. I use Gradle 2.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific: What exactly have you tried, which error did you get, what is the essence of the solution that you linked to ("this")?

Comment: I use two properties to access a private repository that I store in the gradle.properties file. The build fails because of those properties. The solutions I linked shows how to tell the gradle plugin of Jenkins the place where the file can be shared across all jobs.

Comment: What is the error you get? Does the user executing jenkins jobs have access to the `.gradle` directory specified?

Comment: I added -Dgradle.user.home=C:\Users\username\.gradle under  'switches' and the build was succefully executed. Thanks for the reply.