# Jenkins Gradle "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jvm, heap-memory

I'm trying to run a build task with Gradle on Jenkins, but Gradle fails to run.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

Parameter `-Xmx2048m` is apparently used in Java to run Gradle process.
If this parameter is the problem, where should I change it? (Jenkins is configured for `-Xmx1024m`). I'm running it on device with 1GB RAM (about 700 - 500MB free before running the task).

Full log: http://pastebin.com/BBsjp5pZ

Comment: Can you list what all have you tried?

Comment: @ND27 changing heap size of Jenkins in config, trying Gradle with or without deamon, different version of Gradle (latest rc and now 2.10), Gradle wrapper vs Gradle installed by Jenkins, freeing up RAM

Comment: I don't think you'd want to allocate 2GB to Java when the machine only has 500MB free. That would be expected to lead to your build eating more memory than the machine has available, which might be causing yuor crash. In general, I'd advise against running Jenkins on such a tiny machine. If you have to, try allocating *less* memory to gradle, it might work better. But it's likely to crash with a full stack if your build is large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Refuses to Start - Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058471/java-refuses-to-start-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Comment: @Jolta Problem is I don't know how to change JVM parameres of Gradle process in Jenkins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to modify `gradle.properties` file in project folder

Original settings:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

New settings:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -Xms100m
```

References:

[Where should I put gradle.properties in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169638/where-should-i-put-gradle-properties-in-jenkins)
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: While not a bad solution per se, this will impact the build on other servers than the Jenkins host, which might have more available memory. See Jayan's answer for an alternative solution which only takes local effect on the Jenkins host.

Comment: @Jolta Jayan's answer wasn't woking for me, but there is a way to make `gradle.properties` work per machine, not per project

Comment: Nice, finely this helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Jenkins manual](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors) talks about "GRADLE_OPTS".

> Gradle build steps You can set the -Xmx or -XX:MaxPermSize by adding a
>   GRADLE_OPTS global environment variable in the Jenkins global
>   configuration. To do this, click Manage Jenkins, then Configure
>   System. In the Global properties section, click the Environment
>   Variables checkbox, then add a new environment variable called
>   GRADLE_OPTS with the value set appropriately, similar to the screen
>   shot above regarding MAVEN_OPTS